# Как принять от пользователя несколько фотографий в одном сообщение и отправить их обратно?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Возникла проблема, что при отправке пользователем несколько фотографий мною написанный код отправляет 2 сообщения с дубликатами, как решить этот вопрос, чтобы когда пользователь отправлял несколько фотографий в одном сообщении, бот отсылал их ему же также одним сообщением ?

```py
else:
    media_group = []
    sent_photos = []
    # unik_id = []
    media_group.clear()
    sent_photos.clear()
    # unik_id.clear()
    for photo in message.photo:
        if message.photo[-1].file_id not in sent_photos:
            media_group.append(telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(message.photo[-1].file_id))
            # unik_id.append(photo.file_unique_id)
            # sent_photos.append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,media_group)
    bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня сейчас та же проблема. Спрашивал на другом форуме и человек проверил на других библиотеках, всё одинаково. Скорее всего это ошибка API telegram и стоит или ждать фикса, или искать метод обхода